# How to bypass Javascript anti-debugger in chrome web browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, anti-debugging

I'm trying to reverse engineer a heavily obfuscated JS and one of the tricks the author does is to continuously call the debugger statement from within an anonymous function:

[image]

So i will show you how i bypassed anti-debugger and get the code executed, should you be faced with this same challenge.

Check the solution as the answer to this question to bypass this anti-tampering trick

Answer (score 1):

1. **STEP 1**

- Open the chrome dev tool `Ctrl + sift + I`
  . From the web page below, you can see that anti-debugger has been enabled on this website

[image]

2. **STEP 2**

- Click on `Activate Breakpoint` icon or press (Ctrl + F8) - see label 1 arrow on the image
- Click on `pause script execution` icon - see label 2 arrow on the image

[image]

**That is it!!!!**

Comment: Is that persistent? Or does that only works until you refresh the page?

Comment: It is persistent